# could not init GLX in minecraft

Tags: 12.10, minecraft

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Daisy, daisy...

Time: 11/10/13 1:51 AM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not init GLX
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.<init>(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:788)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setPixelFormat(DrawableGL.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:846)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at atv.O(SourceFile:297)
    at atv.d(SourceFile:599)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:101)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.<init>(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:788)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setPixelFormat(DrawableGL.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:846)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at atv.O(SourceFile:297)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at atv.d(SourceFile:599)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:101)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.6.4
    Operating System: Linux (i386) version 3.5.0-43-generic
    Java Version: 1.7.0_25, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK Client VM (mixed mode, sharing), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 5249672 bytes (5 MB) / 26349568 bytes (25 MB) up to 518979584 bytes (494 MB)
    JVM Flags: 1 total; -Xmx512M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Suspicious classes: No suspicious classes found.
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.6.4
    LWJGL: 2.9.0
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `lspci | grep VGA && glxinfo | grep -w 'direct\|OpenGL'` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try these steps?

1. Execute this command in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx
   ```
2. Retry, if that doesn't fix it continue with the next steps.

---

1. Execute this command in a Terminal:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```
2. Add the following to the bottom of that file:

   ```
   Section "Screen"
   Identifier      "Default Screen"
   DefaultDepth    24
   EndSection

   Section "Module"
   Load    "glx"
   EndSection

   Section "Device"
   Identifier      "Default Device"
   Driver  "nvidia"
   Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
   EndSection
   ```
3. Save the file
4. Reboot and retry

Reference:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1810956.html

Comment: I'm sorry but it didn’t work

Comment: @user214294 You can update your question as to how it didn't work and go from there

Comment: it is still crashing and i have tried both of your suggestions.

Comment: i still do not know what to do